# Why $r$ should be $ \in\Bbb Q$ why not $r\in\Bbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

When I look up for properties of the natural Logarithm I found in particular this property

> $$ \ln(x^r)=r \ln(x)  $$
>   with $$x\in  \Bbb R^{+*} $$
>   and$$  r\in\Bbb Q$$

My Question is :  Why  $r$ should be $ \in\Bbb Q$ why not $r\in\Bbb R$

because i can't figure out any  problem with being $ r\in\Bbb R$

Comment: As long as $x>0$, $r$ can be any real number , not only a rational one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the terms you put it, there is really no problem: that identity holds for all $r\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: are you sure Mr Saucy?

Comment: One hundred percent sure. @ElMouden

Answer (score 6):

It should be for all real $r$.  The only reason I can see to restrict to $\Bbb Q$ is if you haven't defined $x^r$ for irrational $r$.  You can define it for rational $r$ based on the definition for integers and the laws of exponents.  Wherever you saw this may not have made the definition for irrational $r$ yet.  That usually goes through defining the exponential function or the natural logarithm, with the natural log defined as the integral of $\frac 1x$

Comment: "The only reason I can see to restrict to $\Bbb Q$ is if you haven't defined $x^r$ for irrational $r$." Or you have defined it for irrational $r$, but proving the property involves quite a bit more machinery than it does for rational $r$.

Comment: i can't understand all of what you said